# How to use scanf to read inputs which are in the form of float1##float2 (i.e., two float numbers separated by two pound signs)

Tags: c

I need to handle inputs in the following ways Enter two float numbers separated by ##:
Input >> 3.19990##9.99921
Output>> 3.19990 + 9.99921 = 13.19911

Comment: What did you try so far? What about `int status = scanf("%f##%f", &f1, &f2);`? Or use `fgets` and `sscanf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    float f1, f2;

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "Please enter two floating-point numbers separated by ##: " );

    //attempt to read and parse user input
    if ( scanf( "%f##%f", &f1, &f2 ) != 2 )
    {
        printf( "Input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //print the result
    printf( "You entered the following two numbers:\n%f\n%f\n", f1, f2 );
}
```

However, using `scanf` for user input is generally not recommended, as it does not behave in an intuitive manner with user input. For example, [it does not always read an entire line of user input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/12149471), which can be confusing and cause trouble.

For this reason, it is usually better to use the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), which always reads an entire line at once, assuming that the supplied memory buffer is large enough. After reading in one line of input as a string using `fgets`, you can then parse the string, for example using the function [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    char line[200];
    float f1, f2;

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "Please enter two floating-point numbers separated by ##: " );

    //attempt to read one line of user input
    if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //attempt to parse the input
    if ( sscanf( line, "%f##%f", &f1, &f2 ) != 2 )
    {
        printf( "Parse error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //print the result
    printf( "You entered the following two numbers:\n%f\n%f\n", f1, f2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C its catered by default, you just need to add Pound (#) signs in `scanf`.

```c
scanf("%f##%f",&x,&y);
```